# Index was out of range c#

Tags: c#

Why i get index was out of range? 
I watched my code many time, and I cannot find where is mistake.
Here is list:

```
 List<PictureBox> bullets = new List<PictureBox>();
 int i=0;
```

Event KeyDown:

```
void Tank_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

        if (e.KeyData== Keys.space)
            {
            if (bullets.Count==0)
                {
                    PictureBox bullet = new PictureBox();
                    kulka.Name = Convert.ToString(i);
                    kulka.Image = new Bitmap("foto/kulka2.png");
                    Random dd = new Random();
                    if (pagr.Name == "RotateW")
                        bullet.Location = new Point(pagr.Location.X + 16, pagr.Location.Y - 8);
                    if (pagr.Name == "RotateS")
                        bullet.Location = new Point(pagr.Location.X + 16, pagr.Location.Y + pagr.Height + 2);
                    if (pagr.Name == "RotateA")
                        bullet.Location = new Point(pagr.Location.X - 8, pagr.Location.Y + 16);
                    if (pagr.Name == "RotateD")
                        bullet.Location = new Point(pagr.Location.X + pagr.Height + 11, pagr.Location.Y + 16);
                    bullet.Width = 5;
                    bullet.Height = 8;
                    bullet.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                    bullet.BringToFront();
                    bullets.Add(bullet);
                    panelis.Controls.Add(bullets[i]);
                    Task task = new Task(() => this.bullet_move(i, pagr.Name));
                    task.Start();
                    this.Refresh();
                }
            }
}
```

And here is my task:

```
void bullet_move(int j,string rotation)
    {
        while (true)
        {
                    if (rotation == "RotateW")
                    {
                            BeginInvoke(new Action(() => bullets[j].Top = bullets[j].Top - 1));

                        if (bullets[j].Top < 2)
                        {
                            BeginInvoke(new Action(() => panelis.Controls.Remove(bullets[j])));
                            bullets.RemoveAt(j);
                            Application.DoEvents();
                            i = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
           } 
      }
```

Sometimes I get here index out of range:

```
BeginInvoke(new Action(() => bullets[j].Top = bullets[j].Top - 1));
```

and sometimes here:

```
  BeginInvoke(new Action(() => panelis.Controls.Remove(bullets[j])));
```

Why I get that error? :/
Thanks for help... :)

Comment: Attach debugger and see where debugger stops.

Comment: i get this error: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index where is this BeginInvoke(new Action(() => bullets[j].Top = bullets[j].Top - 1)); i dont need debug becouse i know place where is error.. :/

Comment: You obviously do need to debug because you have a bug. What is the value of `j` when you get the error?

Comment: 0, and all time j=0... becouse j=i and i==0

Comment: You are dealing with a captured `j`, that could go out of range. But your direct problem is the non-threadsafe usage of `bullets`. A `List<>` simply isn't threadsafe.

Comment: when pressing space button creates new picturebox-bullet. When task just  moving pictutebox up, and when reach top=1 must remove picturebox, but i get that error, he moves and when top=1 i get error.

Comment: I don't know how else to say check how many bullets there are in bullets

Comment: only one element in bullets...

Comment: Did you add any item to the bullets list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by replacing the BeginInvoke with Invoke.  The BeginInvoke is an asynchronous call and you are making it in an extremely tight loop.  The calls may not be executed in the order that they are made.  This will make the code pretty much impossible to debug.

Comment: @user3420235 - This is a band-aid, not a real fundamental solution. You will run into other problems soon.